# How dockerize a serverless project

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a project that uses the serverless framework to deploy lambdas on my AWS environment.
This project is a web server that receives API calls.

However, I have a customer who would like to host it locally on one of his servers using docker.

The problem is that I can't find any solution to dockerize my serverless project.
Is there a way to take this serverless project, dockerize it, deploy this docker and then the customer can make API calls?

The only solution I can think of is to add an abstraction layer and a flask/express server, which converts the API calls into calls to my lambda functions. I'm not sure how clear this is.

I haven't found any solution that does this. Am I the only person facing this situation?

Comment: Maybe Knative is a good fit for your use case: https://knative.dev/docs/concepts/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build your own docker image, based on [`aws/aws-lambda-base-images`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images)

> ### AWS Lambda Base Container Images
>
> AWS provided base images for Lambda contain all the required components to run your functions packaged as container images on AWS Lambda.
>
> These base images contain the Amazon Linux Base operating system, the runtime for a given language, dependencies and the Lambda Runtime Interface Client (RIC), which implements the Lambda Runtime API.
>
> The Lambda Runtime Interface Client allows your runtime to receive requests from and send requests to the Lambda service

Amazon proposes [`aws-lambda-xxx` images](https://hub.docker.com/u/amazon) (`aws-lambda-go`, `aws-lambda-java`, `aws-lambda-python`, ...), or you can build your own, from one of [the many branches](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/branches/all), to add nodejs 12 or 18, ruby, dotnet, ...

From there, you can test your lambda locally: (following [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-python))

> Example Dockerfile below:
>
> ```
> FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
>
> # Copy function code
> COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
>
> # Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
> CMD [ "app.handler" ]
> ```
>
> You can then locally test your function using the docker build and docker run commands.
>
> To build you image:
>
> ```bash
> docker build -t <image name> .
> ```
>
> To run your image locally:
>
> ```bash
> docker run -p 9000:8080 <image name>
> ```
>
> In a separate terminal, you can then locally invoke the function using cURL:
>
> ```bash
> curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'
> ```

---

In your case, using [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs):

```bash
serverless create --template aws-python3 --path my-lambda-container
cd my-lambda-container
```

Create a Dockerfile in the root directory of your Serverless project.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "handler.my_handler" ]
```

Build and run your Docker container as per the instructions:

```bash
docker build -t my-lambda-container-image .
docker run -p 9000:8080 my-lambda-container-image
```

Test with cURL:

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

To deploy your container image using Serverless Framework, update `serverless.yml` to use the AWS provided Lambda container image.

If you are deploying to AWS directly, you would need to push the Docker image to ECR and then use that ECR image URI in your `serverless.yml`.

```yaml
service: my-lambda-container

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  ecr:
    images:
      mylambdaimage:
        path: ./
        file: Dockerfile

functions:
  myFunction:
    image:
      name: mylambdaimage
```

That setup tells the Serverless Framework to build the Docker image and push it to ECR.

```bash
serverless deploy
```

That command will package your code, build your Docker image, push it to ECR, and then deploy the Lambda function using that container image.

For local development, you would still use Docker directly to run and test your Lambda container. However, if you want an experience more aligned with the Serverless Framework, consider using tools like [`serverless-offline`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline) or [`serverless-localstack`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-localstack). These can emulate AWS services locally, but would need adjustments to work seamlessly with Lambda containers.

---

> It works well.
>
> However, it only handles lambdas calls, not HTTP API calls. Do you know if there is a way to cumulate the 2? That is, to be able to invoke lambdas via HTTP calls, but also to be able to call lambdas via API calls?
>
> For example, in my serverless I have a function:`- http: path: /helloWorld method: get`.
> Using a server like unicorn/flask or something else?

What you would be creating is a local emulation of AWS API Gateway in conjunction with Lambda.

If you are setting up a local development environment where Flask acts as a mock for the AWS API Gateway and your Lambda functions run in Docker containers, then you would install Flask locally.

```bash
pip install Flask
```

And you create a Flask app to route HTTP requests to the appropriate Docker Lambda container:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/helloWorld', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    # Call the Docker Lambda function
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations",
                            json=request.get_json())

    return jsonify(response.json()), response.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000)
```

That Flask app listens for requests on `/helloWorld` and forwards the payload to your Docker Lambda container.
Make sure your Docker Lambda container is running. Then run the Flask app:

```bash
python your_flask_app.py
```

Now that your Flask server is running on port 3000, you can test it out:

```bash
curl http://localhost:3000/helloWorld
```

And also directly invoke Lambdas:

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

---

But if you are planning to distribute a single Docker container that includes both the Flask app and the Lambda function (or multiple functions), then you would install Flask and your Flask appplication in the Dockerfile.

Apologies for the oversight. In the second scenario, where Flask is inside the Docker container, the Flask app is included in the Docker image itself. The `COPY` command in the Dockerfile ensures this.

Your Flask app could be named, for instance, `your_flask_app.py`. That Flask app would define your routes and handle forwarding requests to the Lambda runtime API *inside* the Docker container.

```py
# your_flask_app.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/helloWorld', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations",
                            json=request.get_json())

    return jsonify(response.json()), response.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```

Your Dockerfile would then be:

```
# Use the AWS base image for the Lambda runtime
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Install Flask
RUN pip install Flask requests

# Copy Flask app and Lambda function code into the Docker image
COPY your_flask_app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
COPY handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

# Set the CMD to run Flask
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=3000"]
```

It means the Flask app (`your_flask_app.py`) is copied into the Docker image at the `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}` directory, which is where the Lambda runtime will expect to find the code. That ensures that when the Docker container is started, the Flask app will be available to run.

```bash
docker build -t my-lambda-flask-container .
docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 9000:9000 my-lambda-flask-container
```

We map both port 3000 (for the Flask app) and port 9000 (for direct Lambda invocations) from the container to the host. That allows you to test the Flask routes and also directly invoke the Lambda function inside the container.

---

> Do you think such an architecture can be deployed in production? You're talking about a local test environment

The first one (Flask App + Lambda functions run in Docker containers) is more complex to manage in production: you deploy two elements, and careful consideration must be given to scaling, monitoring, and logging. Make sure that any environment variables or configuration settings needed by the Flask app are set correctly in your production environment.

The second one (container with AWS Lambda + Flask app) is simpler to deployed, and the monitoring, logging, and scaling strategies should be in place in that container.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. However, it only handles lambdas calls, not HTTP API calls. Do you know if there is a way to cumulate the 2? That is, to be able to invoke lambdas via HTTP calls, but also to be able to call lambdas via API calls? for example, in my serverless I have a function: - http:
          path: /helloWorld
          method: get

Using a server like uvicorn/flask or something else?

Comment: @MathAng OK, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanations. Do you think such an architecture can be deployed in production? You're talking about a local test environment.

Comment: @MathAng But which architecture? One where you install Flask on the server, separately from Docker? Or one where you deploy a Docker container with the Flask app in it?

Comment: @MathAng I have edited the answer to address both architectures.